# Includes without local server?

Tags: html, include, ssi, client-side

I'm making a website, and I like testing everything offline instead of having to upload files with every change I make. The problem is I can't use includes, so when I do upload, I'm going to have to change a lot of the file structure.

I'm not looking to install a local server like WAMP when I just want to use includes. Is there any way?

Comment: Nope. But if all you want to do is use includes, then you don't need WAMP, you just need a web server, such as the "A" part of WAMP, or IIS, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

You could process includes statically (e.g., write yourself a Makefile to create the actual HTML files you view locally). There are plenty of template languages out there that could do this. You could, I suppose, even write your templates in JavaScript and let the web browser assemble them.

But really, why *wouldn't* you want your test environment to match your production environment? This seems silly—if there is something wrong with your includes, you want to find out before you make it live. If you accidentally get a local path to an image (`C:\Documents and Settings\…\image.png`) in a file, you want to find out.  The best way to do this is really to run a webserver locally.

Comment: Replicating production on the test machine might be more difficult if development is done on a compact laptop or if production uses server software whose license requires additional payment per machine.

Comment: @tepples Sure, it might be, but OP was talking about a Apache-MySQL-PHP stack, which is free software and also runs on practically anything. Also, even if dev is done from a machine that has, e.g., insufficient RAM to run part of the stack, the test environment can be run elsewhere. Of course, budgets don't always allow, but I think you'd still want it, even though you can't afford it.