# Include HTML file via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a file stored locally, not on a server, so Server Side Includes do not work.

### Problem:

I have an HTML file. There is lots of data in it, I want to split it into smaller parts, and then just include them all into my big html file, i.e. something like:

```
main.html
  <include "partA.html">
  <include "partB.html">
  <include "partC.html">
```

And I want the result as if the contents of partA,B,C.html were read right into main.html

Now, this is not on a server -- it's stored locally, so I can't do SSI. My question is:

Is there some simple way to do this via JavaScript? It seems like with JavaScript, I shoudl be able to:

- fetch the contents of blah.html [not sure how to do this ste[
- call a document.write on it, to write it into the document
- probably handle some stuff dealing with escaping strings

### Question:

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: if the code is stored locally and the page is not dynamic, there is no point using javascript, simply add your html to the page directly

Comment: This is a very big HTML document. I want it to be in separate files for simpler editing. I.e. one HTML file per section.

Comment: @user1383359: With modern IDEs and code folding, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have bad habits, and, in VIM, like to use 1G and GG to move to the beginning / end of a single section. Otherwise, I'd have to deal with folds + using / to search for sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, as a security feature. This post here is a discussion on the topic - [Includes without local server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880942/includes-without-local-server). As the answers say, your best best is to install a small web server on the machine if you can. They're not too hard to get going.

I have used nginx before with good results. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx

Comment: Thanks @Rocket - was on my iPod!

Answer (score 1):

HTML5Rocks has a tutorial on how to read local files using HTML5's File API:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Outside this, Javascript generally does not have the ability to access local filesystems.

*Update* - I assumed the main file was on a server, and you wanted that file to access local files. On re-reading, it appears all your files are local, in which case, some of the answers below will work.